# Input bar delay after lots of user interaction

Tags: angular, input

I've been trying to debug this issue for a while now but it seems I can't make sense of it.

I have a Angular webshop. On the product overview page we currently load a product component which consists of a lazy loaded, very compressed image. a title, input for amount, input for size and a buy button.

This component is rendered 100 times on the page (each page has 100 product items. We are currently looking at lowering this value but this does not seem to help with this issue)

Whenever a user has added about say 10+ items in their cart (which happens way more often in our case) the search input in the filter sidebar is heavily lagged/delayed.

This only happens when we interact with the product component. My first guess would be that it has something to do with changeDetection.

I realise this is very little information. I tried to reproduce this in an isolated stackblitz environment but I can't seem to get it to happen there.

So instead of the actual answer of course I was hoping someone might haven an rough idea and point me in that direction.

Many thanks

Comment: Doesn't `OnPush` strategy help?

Comment: changeDetection is a right guess I would say. Also consider changing your UX to make it more performant. For example don't render too many details of product at once. But provide a button to expand (*ngIf) other fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from this:

1. Use `OnPush` strategy by default
2. Separate your input element and list component in different components.
3. Don't use performance heavy functions in your templates. Do it in ts file.
4. Don't use any `filtering` pipes.
5. You can use pure pipes to increase performance since they cache results.
6. Use `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged` on your input.
7. Use `TrackBy` function on your `ngFor` directives.
8. Be sure you used `runOutsideAngular` wherever it's reasonable.
9. Be sure you don't have unnecessary DOM manipulations which cause DOM `reflow`.
10. Move as many Angular animations to CSS as possible.
11. Always unsubscribe from observables when a component is destroyed.

To Be Continued...

Comment: Many thanks after a couple of edits I did a couple of things on this list over the complete application but mostly on the component where I noticed it happening.

I've added the OnPush strategy for one and I have added the runOutsideAngular on some global scrollEvents that were added as fallback for a Intersection Observer implementation.